# Can't create a data source in Curity due to licensing issue

Tags: curity

I am following the [getting started guide](https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/getting-started/intro/) to setup an instance of the Curity Identity Server. When going through the basic setup wizard, however, I am told to contact sales when trying to create a data source for user accounts. Specifically, I see this warning which reads:

> To setup this data source, contact sales to obtain a license.

Here's a screenshot of this:

[image: Warning on Account Data Source]

What should I do at this point? I have a license, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license key already, fixing this can be done in the UI by going to the System -> General page and uploading it:

[image: Upload existing license in the Curity admin UI]

There are other ways to install the license as well; check [the manual](https://developer.curity.io/docs/latest/) for details.